# C# Anonymous type `ToString` complicated?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, roslyn, anonymous-types

Does anyone know why anonymous types in C# use such a complicated implementation for `ToString`? I believe earlier versions used a simpler `StringBuilder` implementation.

Here is a sample `ToString` from ILSpy:

```
public override string ToString() {
    object[] array = new object[2];
    <a>j__TPar val = <a>i__Field;
    ref <a>j__TPar reference = ref val;
    <a>j__TPar val2 = default(<a>j__TPar);
    object obj;
    if (val2 == null) {
        val2 = reference;
        reference = ref val2;
        if (val2 == null) {
            obj = null;
            goto IL_0046;
        }
    }
    obj = reference.ToString();
    goto IL_0046;
    IL_0046:
    array[0] = obj;
    <b>j__TPar val3 = <b>i__Field;
    ref <b>j__TPar reference2 = ref val3;
    <b>j__TPar val4 = default(<b>j__TPar);
    object obj2;
    if (val4 == null) {
        val4 = reference2;
        reference2 = ref val4;
        if (val4 == null) {
            obj2 = null;
            goto IL_0081;
        }
    }
    obj2 = reference2.ToString();
    goto IL_0081;
    IL_0081:
    array[1] = obj2;
    return string.Format(null, "{{ a = {0}, b = {1} }}", array);
}
```

Comment: I strongly disagree that this is opinion based, bat that's StackOverflow for you. Someone knows the actual facts in question, and there may even be a Github issue explain or submit explaining the change...

Comment: The C# compiler generates the weird code pattern with ref-assignment whenever the `?.` operator is applied to an unconstrained type parameter. https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/issues/1050

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, but I wonder what the justification is for the pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viewing [blame](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blame/65d799af3a796c7928c5a6acfc961a15c9916d5f/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Compiler/AnonymousTypeMethodBodySynthesizer.cs#L241) of [`AnonymousTypeMethodBodySynthesizer.AnonymousTypeToStringMethodSymbol`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Compiler/AnonymousTypeMethodBodySynthesizer.cs#L241) it seems that for Roslyn compiler implementation via `string.Format` was made from the start. Why it is implemented this way I dont't know. Since it is compiler I would assume that performance and maintainability reasons were taken into consideration (not simplicity of generated code). Would not say that previous implementation was slower or faster though cause `string.Format` internally seems to use `StringBuilder` with some caching magic.

**UPD**

It seems that before `Roslyn` was introduced compiler really generated `StrinBuilder` implementation. From *Pro C# 2008 and the .NET 3.5 Platform* By Andrew Troelsen:

> All anonymous types automatically derive from System.Object and are provided with an overridden version of Equals(), GetHashCode(), and ToString(). The ToString() implementation simply builds a string from each name/value pair, for example:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); builder.Append("{ Color = "); 
    builder.Append(this.<Color>i__Field); builder.Append(", Make = "); 
    builder.Append(this.<Make>i__Field); builder.Append(", CurrentSpeed = "); 
    builder.Append(this.<CurrentSpeed>i__Field); builder.Append(" }");
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

I've written [small benchmark](https://pastebin.com/fX1Vm8XM)(not sure how correct it is though =) and it seems that old implementation was faster.

Also found issue on github([Generate more efficient anonymous type members](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5475)) which among other things raises concern about `ToString`'s performance but in comments was raised valid question:

> Is it common to use anonymous types for their ToString representation? I doubt most people will ever call ToString on one of these. They will be passed to a serializer which will do a different representation or be used as a grouping key in LINQ.

Comment: As the question was unfortunately closed, I will give you the answer as coming close to correct. I did see that github issue but I think it is tangential to why `ToString` was made so much more complicated, though I begin to believe it may be to minimize boxing and/or help the JIT optimize when the method is constructed for concrete types at runtime.

Comment: BTW, what did you mean by "blame of"?

Comment: @NetMage thank you. Simple git blame.